# RANK() function with over is creating ranks dynamically for every run

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am creating ranks for partitions of my table. Partitions are performed by name column with ordered by its transaction value. While I am generating these partitions and checking count for each of the ranks, I get different number in each rank for every query run I do.

```
select count(*)  FROM (
                        --
                        -- Sort and ranks the element of RFM
                        --
                        SELECT
                            *,
                            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_since_last_trans desc) AS rfmrank_r,
                        FROM (
                            SELECT
                                name,
                                id_customer,
                                cust_age,
                                gender,
                                DATE_DIFF(entity_max_date, customer_max_date, DAY ) AS date_since_last_trans,
                                txncnt,
                                txnval,
                                txnval / txncnt AS avg_txnval
                            FROM 
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    name,
                                    id_customer,
                                    MAX(cust_age) AS cust_age,
                                 COALESCE(APPROX_TOP_COUNT(cust_gender,1)[OFFSET(0)].VALUE, MAX(cust_gender)) AS gender,
                                    MAX(date_date) AS customer_max_date,
                                    (SELECT MAX(date_date) FROM xxxxx) AS entity_max_date,
                                    COUNT(purchase_amount) AS txncnt,
                                    SUM(purchase_amount) AS txnval
                                FROM
                                    xxxxx
                                WHERE
                                date_date > (
                                    SELECT
                                        DATE_SUB(MAX(date_date), INTERVAL 24 MONTH) AS max_date
                                    FROM
                                        xxxxx)
                                AND cust_age >= 15
                                AND cust_gender IN ('M','F')
                                GROUP BY
                                    name,
                                    id_customer
                            )
                        )
                    )
          group by rfmrank_r
```

For 1st run I am getting

```
Row f0
1 3970
2 3017
3 2116
4 2118
```

For 2nd run I am getting

```
Row f0
1 4060
2 3233
3 2260
4 2145
```

What can be done, If I need to get same number of partitions getting ranked same for each run
Edit:
Sorry for the blurring of fields
[This is the output of field ```query to get this column````](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utFMh.png)

Comment: How does the data look like before the final COUNT(*) ? Did the data change in any way between the 2 runs?

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: Also, are you sure there's nothing in "query to get this columns" that might be changing the initial input into the partition?

Comment: @ECris, Do you mean the schema of table created prior to partition function?

Comment: @PankajGabale, I mean the data returned by the inner select, before you apply the SELECT COUNT(*), when you calculate RANK

Comment: Hi @Ecris, Thanks for quick response. Here's is short schema, as I don't have a table for that query    /n"name": "integer",
    "id_customer": "integer",
    "cust_age": "Integer",
    "gender": "Char",
    "date_since_last_trans": "Integer",
    "txncnt": "Integer",
    "txnval": "Float",
    "avg_txnval": "Float"

Comment: @wheresmycookie

Comment: You may get different results each time, because the "entity max date" on which the ranking depends also presumably changes and changes the order of things. Also, your naming scheme in this query is appalling!

Comment: @steve, Thanks Steve. I had to replace few column names coz of sensitive info. Thanks for suggestion anyways. Well, the entity_max_date is same for my every run as I am debugging.

Comment: @PankajGabale, is there a time component in these dates then, maybe? I think the best approach would probably be to rewrite this query so that the date filters can be set to a specific range (rather than just going back relative from the current time), and investigate how the results change over time. I can't see exactly where because of the naming scheme and the layers of aggregation, but I can say with reasonable confidence that the date calculations are going to be the source of the problem here.

Comment: @Steve, I think it will be better if I rewrite. Thanks for your time. I'll get back if it works the other way

Comment: Hey @Steve, A quick update. I removed date part from my calculations at all and just calculating on the transaction value and count but buckets are still different in sizes for different run

Comment: @PankajGabale, if you remove any date filtering, then you are still getting a variable date range of data (assuming the system is live and in use). You need to specify *both ends* of the date range for reproducible results.

Comment: @steve. No the system is not live. This is a stage setup I am currently working on

Comment: `I had to replace few column names coz of sensitive info` - this is usually source of problem in presenting question/issue in such a way that there is no way to help. the query as it is presented (after your obfuscation) is NO WAY to produce different result each time (unless underlying data is changed in between runs) - I recommend you to present [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can really help you instead of wasting each other's time. don't tell the data is sensitive! just follow provided link and create example to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RANK window function determines the rank of a value in a group of values.
Each value is ranked within its partition. Rows with equal values for the ranking criteria receive the same rank. Drill adds the number of tied rows to the tied rank to calculate the next rank and thus the ranks might not be consecutive numbers.

For example, if two rows are ranked 1, the next rank is 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @guillermo rojas, but I have tried using Desne_rank function as well, as it wont skip ranks. This still gives me different partitions